# How do I change the style of a ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

I'm working with a plot like this one:

[image]

I'd like to change the style of a `ListPlot` to achieve a style like:

[image]

What options can I use for:

1. Put the X-label and Y-label just at the center of their respective axis.
2. Close the top and right side with a grid.
3. Put the plot name at the top of the plot
4. Include the legend inside the plot itself

These are the plotting options I'm using now:

```
PlotSED60y5103z0code4edgeon[[i]] = 
 ListLogLogPlot[SED60y5103z0code4edgeon[[i]], 
  PlotStyle -> {colors[[i]], Thickness[th]}, AxesLabel -> {"LEGENDS"}, 
PlotRange -> {{10^3, 10^7}, {10^10, 10^14}}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.1}, Joined -> True , 
  PlotLegends -> {StringTemplate[
      "60 d5103 z0 mc CHAB \
Code ``"][codigo60y5103z0code4[[i]]], LegendMarkerSize -> 0.3}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 10}]
```

Any help for any of these points is of great help. Thank you!

Comment: Look at the documentation and examples of e.g. [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html). To give you a few pointers: [`Frame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Frame.html), [`FrameLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel.html), [`PlotLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabel.html), [`Placed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html) (for [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html))

Answer (score 1):

The major point you are missing is that you don't want *axes* but you want a  *frame*. The rest is looking up options and usage. Here is a simple example to give you a start

```
ListLogLogPlot[
 Table[{k, PDF[BinomialDistribution[50, p], k]}, {p, {0.3, 0.5, 0.8}}, {k, 0, 50}],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{0.3, 0.5, 0.8}, {.8, .3}],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"This is the x-axis", "This is the y-axis"},
 PlotLabel -> "This is the title of the plot"
 ]
```

[image]